# Pulling XML element use C#; loop fails

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get hourly weather forecast from wunderground. I can get the weather data for the 1st hour, however the loop fails to pull back the data of next a few hours. I am wondering how to revise the code. The URL for wunderground is http://api.wunderground.com/api/b6fa7ac0ff6723ec/geolookup/hourly/q/MI/Ann_Arbor.xml

I am new to C#. So if you have better ways to do this, I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

```
private static void parse2(string input_xml2)
        {
            string hour = "";
            string tempEn = "";
            string tempMe = "";

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(input_xml2);

            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast");

            foreach (XmlNode xnFore in xnList)
            {


                XmlNode xnHour = xml.SelectSingleNode("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast/FCTTIME");
                XmlNode xnTemp = xml.SelectSingleNode("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast/temp");

                hour = xnHour["hour"].InnerText;
                tempEn = xnTemp["english"].InnerText;
                tempMe = xnTemp["metric"].InnerText;

                Console.WriteLine("********************");
                Console.WriteLine("hour:              " + hour);
                Console.WriteLine("Temperature:       " + tempEn + " F" + " (" + tempMe + " C)");
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are multiple hours already in the response... Personally I would get JSON version http://api.wunderground.com/api/b6fa7ac0ff6723ec/geolookup/hourly/q/MI/Ann_Arbor.json, generate classes http://json2csharp.com/ and use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json for parsing...

Comment: You are not using xnFore  anywhere inside your foreach

Comment: Okay, I will check json. But for my code, the results of multiple hours are the same. I can only get the hour and temperature for the 1st hour. Any comments? Thx~

Comment: As Rodrigo says you're not using `xnFore`. You're re-doing the query from the root every time so you always get the first instance. Instead of `xml.SelectSingleNode("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast/FCTTIME")` change to `xnFore.SelectSingleNode("FCTTIME")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rodrigo and  Steve!@RodrigoLópez@steve16351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be inclined to ditch the ancient `XmlDocument` API and use LINQ to XML:

```
const string url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/b6fa7ac0ff6723ec/geolookup/hourly/q/MI/Ann_Arbor.xml";

var doc = XDocument.Load(url);

var forecasts = doc.Descendants("hourly_forecast").Elements("forecast");

foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
{
    var hour = (string)forecast.Elements("FCTTIME").Elements("hour").Single();
    var english = (int)forecast.Elements("temp").Elements("english").Single();
    var metric = (int)forecast.Elements("temp").Elements("metric").Single();

    Console.WriteLine("********************");
    Console.WriteLine("Hour:\t\t{0}", hour);
    Console.WriteLine("Temperature:\t{0}F ({1}C)", english, metric);
}
```

A working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q1CZsE

If you have the XML string already, you can parse rather than load it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```